# POSIX Search in variable length character string

Tags: regex, postgresql, posix

I have the following three strings and I would like to capture the branch_number result for each of the four examples. I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4

```
ex.1) "decision => approved ,  branch_number => 1126 , alpha"
ex.2) "decision => counter ,  branch_number => 249 , beta"
ex.3) "decision => declined ,  branch_number =>NULL, gamma"
ex.4) "decision => declined ,  branch_number => 91"
```

My current query is as follows with corresponding results and desired results:

```
trim(substring(replace(e.meta,'_','') from '%branchnumber =>#"_____#"%' for '#'))

results 1) "1126" (desired "1126")
results 2) "249" (desired "249")
results 3) "NULL," (desired "NULL")
results 4) <null> (desired "91")
```

I'm having trouble determining what to put between the # qualifiers since the result set could be a space then 2 digits, a space then 3 digits,  a space then 4 digits, or simply 4 text characters.

Comment: Not very familiar with Postgres, but if you can use regular expressions here, can't you just say `(\d+|NULL)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with the following regex

```
trim(substring(e.meta from '%branchnumber =>([A-Z]{4}| [0-9]{1,5}))
```